Create and write to a real file in JUnit test case
I have a unit test case in Android where I want to create a new file and write data to it. This file needs to be manually analysed later so cannot use TemporaryFolder().
Is there any way to create a file in the project directory from the test case?
Cannot wrote to assets or resources as they are not writable from test case.
